# Required permissions to read from a farm's property bag?

Tags: 2010, 2013, permissions, properties

Which permissions are required to read from a farm's property bag?

Background: The property bag needs to be accessed read-only from a .NET application which runs under a specific user account on any of the farm servers. Which permissions are needed for this account (in SharePoint? on the Config DB? ...)? Are there any other precautions to be taken?

Answer (score 3):

Any user account present in the farm administrator group (CA - Security - Farm Administrators) has access to farm property bag. This access can be also verified by logging into any of the servers in the farm and running Get-SPFarm in the SharePoint powershell.

Since you have mentioned it will be used for read-only purposes from a .NET application, its not perhaps a best practice to expose the farm configuration directly through a farm administrator account. I'd rather make a small web service that runs  in the context of farm app pool service account and connects to the farm on the context of an exisiting farm administrator.  The .NET Application only interacts with the web service in a read only mode to retrieve details based on SOAP requests and nothing else.  This way I end up isolating my farm property bag from unauthorized administrative calls.